# Parse warning from didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am getting an error after adding this code from parse.com:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }
}
```

I don't really understand what is going on, but I am getting this warning in the log:

> You've implemented -[
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but
>   you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your
>   supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.

I think adding in your plist file `UIBackgroundModes - remote-notification` would fix the problem,

But when I do that, it changes the words to the follow:

`Required Background Modes` -> `App downloads content in response to push notifications`

Which my app doesn't do, so I am confused as to why I am doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you don't intend to fetch data in response to a remote notification I think you can implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

e.g.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }
}
```

instead of the current one you're using.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed: if you follow the parse guide(s), the assumption is you want to background-download data via pushes. I don't. So this answer is correct for me.

Comment: The main difference being that you are NOT implementing the `fetchCompletionHandler:` version of the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` methods.

Comment: In iOS 10 `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` is deprecated

Answer (score 212):

If you don't want to manually add key in your `.plist` file then here's a graphical version of @MurraySagal's answer, follow the steps from 1 to 7 and you'll be done. :)

[image]

Note: If you can't read out the steps, you can zoom out your current tab by using combination of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (for zoom in) and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (for zoom out). If <kbd>Command</kbd> won't work, you can try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: This fixed the GCM issues I was having. This is a good way of doing it

Comment: perfect solution!

Answer (score 38):

I think @djshiow is not solving your problem.

You need to add the following in your info.plist file:

[image: remote-notification]

1) Add a new row and, on the left column, select **Required background modes**.

2) On Item 0 row, click on the right column and type: **remote-notification**. Press Enter.

Source: http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/

Answer (score 22):

In Xcode 6:

- In the Project Navigator click the project
- In the Projects and Targets list click the target.
- Click Capabilities
- Expand and turn on Background Modes
- Click Remote Notifications

This will add the `Required background modes` key and `App downloads content in response to push notifications` value to `info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the new didReceive... method you are expected to do two things:

1. Add the necessary entry in your plist
2. Add a completion handler that will handle the event for handling the data

If you do not want to download any data, you can add this to your didReceive... method

```
completionHandler(.NoData)
```