# Is it possible for unity3D game app to request a webservice when the app is in the background for iOS7

Tags: ios7, unity-game-engine

Could any help in creating a Unity3D App which could request some data from some webservice (let say every 5 mins) and send a local notification while the game app is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AppController class that the Unity player creates. You need to respond to some of these messages:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

These are called when the application goes from the background to active and vice-versa. If you want to communicate with unity, you can pass some info with:

```
UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "InBackground", "Message to send");
```

If you send the message in `(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`
, the method **InBackground()** will be called. You can have coroutine in that method with is called in every fixed time. This is a theory. Try to implement it.

Comment: And you need to configure your app to do this. See [How to enable background update on iOS 7 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741265/how-to-enable-background-update-on-ios-7-apps) for example.